# find any document which holds in array property a substring of any of the elements in array passed to the query with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating an online cook book and came across an issue wen trying to query MongoDB.
users can select multiple ingredients which in turn will be passed as an array to query the DB using [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/).
In the DB for every document there's a field -ingredients, with `type:Array` , which i want to query. the problem is that banana for example, can be saved in the DB as "5 ripe bananas" and the user can only select the substring "banana" .so in other words, how can i find any document in the database which includes in its ingredients array a substring of any of the elements in the array passed?

i did manage to find a match without the substring part:

```
app.get('/recipe', (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.ingredients){
        let ingredients = req.query.ingredients.map(x => JSON.parse(x).name);

        // find any document to include in its ingredients list a substring of any of the elements in the ingredients array
        Recipe.find({ingredients: {$in: ingredients}}).then((recipes) => {
            console.log("recipes" + recipes);
            if (!recipes) {
                res.status(404).send();
            }
            res.status(200).send(recipes);
        }, (e) => {
            res.status(400).send();
        })
    }
});
```

but how can i add the substring issue ("5 ripe bananas" - "banana")??
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression `$regex` and search your array of ingredients like so:

```
Recipe.find({ingredients: { $regex: /banana/ }}).then((recipes) => ...
```

In your case since you have an array to be used as a `filter` you could run those queries individually in combination with `Promise.map`. Something among the lines of:

```
app.get('/recipe', (req, res) => {
   if (req.query.ingredients) {
       let ingredientMap = req.query.ingredients.map(x => 
          Recipe.find({ingredients: {$regex: new RegExp(JSON.parse(x).name})}});

       return Promise.all(ingredientMap).then((results) => ... )
    }
});
```

Then from the `Promise.map` results array you would get for each ingredient the matching doucments.

Comment: tried to work with but keep getting `TypeError: Promise.map is not a function
`

Comment: Yeah I meant `all` not map there since you already `mapped` them above.